# Connecting two Tables using a third Table (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to write a query to produce a column with text values from one table that is has code relevent to a second table which has keys relevent to a third table in which I want to put the colmun. The second table has a column with keys to the relevent elements in the first table and keys relevent to the third table. The third table is a log of occurances related to the secondtable. Ill try to illustrate below:

```
First Table                  Second Table                 Third Table
Name1 | Code1          Code1  |  Name2  | Code2              Code 2
-------------         --------------------------          -----------
Red   |   1              1    |  Ball   |  10                  10
Blue  |   2              2    |  Toy    |  20                  20
Green |   3              3    |  Grass  |  30                  30
```

The tricky part is I need both Names as separte columns in the third table. Not sure if it matters but the third table has a bunch of other columns with other codes that I have already joined with other tables.

Should look like this:

```
    Third Table
 Name1  |  Name2 
-----------------
  Red   |  Ball   
  Blue  |  Toy    
  Green |  Grass
```

Comment: I'm still in the process of learning SQL, so I tried:
     
     `SELECT Table1.Name1, Table2.Name2 FROM Table3 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table3.code2=Table2.code2 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.code1=Table1.code1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT       first.Name1,
             second.Name2
FROM         firstTable first
LEFT JOIN    secondTable second ON first.Code1 = second.code1
INNER JOIN   thirdTable third ON second.code2 = third.code2
```

You can see this here->http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17883/2

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hey yes tx this seems to work nicely. Ill try to incoperate it into the rest of the query I have for table 3 and come back with an update!

Answer (score 0):

On a high level,
You may want to do this:

```
select t1.name1, t2.name2 from t1,t2,t3 where t3.code2=t2.code2 and t1.code1 = t2.code1
```